# How to get child Activity View in Parent Activity Class(Android)?

Tags: android

I implemented a bottom button bar(something like a tab bar controller in iPhone). For this I created a common layout (button_bar.xml, 5 image buttons) and included in other activity xml files. and for the managing the click action I created a BaseActivity.java extended from Activity and perform the click actions. and I extend other activity which need button bar from this BaseActivity, which works fine. Now I want to include a selected state to these buttons, but when I access the buttons in base activity it give a null pointer error. How can I solve this.

button_bar.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/bottomButtonBar"
style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
... >
<ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/btnGuests"
    android:onClick="showAllGuests"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_guest_list" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnAddGuest"
    android:onClick="selectGuestType"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_guest" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnAddParty"
    android:onClick="showAddParty"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_party" />
    ....
</LinearLayout>

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    // common to other activities.
    public void showAddParty(View view) {
    //showAddParty is one one of the buttons click method. 4 more buttons are there
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddPartyActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        // I can get "view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddParty)" here
        // but I can't get "findViewById(R.id.btnAddGuest)" here. how this possible
    }
}

public class AddPartyActivity extends BaseActivity{
    ....
}
```

Here i can get the corresponding view from parameter view, and change backgroundIbageSource. but when it goes to "AddPartyActivity" that inherited from Baseactivity, the new image is replaced by old one. How can I implement the selected feature in BaseActivity itself?

Comment: Make a Object of Your Parent Activity and access from it

Comment: @PiyushGupta make a Object of Activity??? how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can hold the state of the Button(clicked or not) using `booloean` in BaseActivity and check the value of these variables in AddPropertyActivity's `onCreate()` method.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    protected static boolean isButton1Clicked = false;
    protected static boolean isButton2Clicked = false;
    protected static boolean isButton3Clicked = false;
    protected static boolean isButton4Clicked = false;
    .....
    public void showAddParty(View view) {
       isButton1Clicked = true;
      //showAddParty is one one of the buttons click method. 4 more buttons are there
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddPartyActivity.class); 
       startActivity(intent);
    }
}


public class AddPartyActivity extends BaseActivity {

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
         Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
         if(isButton1Clicked) {
             button1.setBackground(R.drawable.clicked);
         } else {
             button1.setBackground(R.drawable.not_clicked);
         }
      ......
      ......
      }
}
```

and remember that all boolean variables must be `static` variables. (every object will have it's own copy of instance variables but all objects will share a single copy of static members).

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    protected static boolean isButton1Clicked = false;
    protected static boolean isButton2Clicked = false;
    protected static boolean isButton3Clicked = false;
    protected static boolean isButton4Clicked = false;
    protected Button button1;
    protected Button button2;
    protected Button button3;
    protected Button button4;

    protected void checkButtonsState() {
        if (isButton1Clicked) {
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);
        } else {
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);
        }
       ..........
    }

    public void showAddParty(View view) {
        isButton1Clicked = true;
        // showAddParty is one one of the buttons click method. 4 more
        // buttons are there
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddPartyActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public class AddPartyActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.item1);
          .....
        checkButtonsState();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes that is one solution, but the problem is many activity inherit base activity, so i need to write the code every where. that why i look something can do in the BaseActivity itself.

Comment: @bolt123 if all activities layouts have same Buttons with same Id, you can move initialization part to Base Activity.(write one method in Base Activity like initializeButtons() and call that method in ChildActivity after setting contentView

Comment: Thanks Gopal Rao. It is a common bottom bar with 5 buttons. I did the initialization part in Base activity itself. Also showAddParty() have many child activity, and selection need to exist in that activity also. i managed that using global state. Tab bar works fine now. One problem is need to call checkButtonsState() in all inherited activities(more than 15). Can we avoid that(in BaseActivity Itself)

Comment: @bolt123 override onStart() method in BaseActivity and call checkButtonsState() in that. be sure that all Buttons are instantiated before onStart()

Answer (score 0):

Your error come from because you are using `view.findViewById()`, but the view variable correspond of the object that catch the click event (look in your xml, the `'android:onClick="showAddParty"')`.

So, you have in parameter a view instance that point directly to the `btnAddParty` button.
Is why you can access with `findViewById` to `btnAddParty` id but not `btnAddGuest` id.

You can access to all the view hierarchy by using direct findViewById as method of the activity class:

```
 View btAddParty = findViewById(R.id.btnAddParty)

 View btAddGuest = view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddGuest)
```

Now, you can have a full solution, by implement a special method (`setMyInternalContent` in the sample below) in the `BaseActivity` and keep an instance of each button, after, you just have to update there state on click action:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    protected Button mBtAddParty;
    protected Button mBtAddGuest;
    // ...

    protected void setMyContentView(int resId) {
        setContentView(resId);
        mBtAddParty = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddParty);            
        mBtAddParty = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddGuest);   
        // ...            
    }

    public void showAddParty(View view) {
        mBtAddParty.setClickable(true);
        mBtAddGuest.setClickable(false);
        // ...

        //showAddParty is one one of the buttons click method. 4 more buttons are there
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddPartyActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}


public class AddPartyActivity extends BaseActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setMyContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

        // Do not forget to set initial button state:            
        mBtAddParty.setClickable(true);
        mBtAddGuest.setClickable(false);
        // ...
    }
}
```